# C extract word from a string between two words

Tags: c, extract, delimiter

i am writing a C program and one of the issues i have is to extract a word between two words as below.

```
ac_auto_lvalue[] =
    "ONLY / GROUP:  OTHERS EXAMPLE  /-----------------------------";
```

I need to extract the word between "Group:" and the "/", the two words (Group:" & "/") will always be there but the words in between can change and in some cases there might be nothing... ( in the above example output would be "OTHERS EXAMPLE"

can anyone help me with a C snippet for the above?

Comment: Can you show any code that you have so far? `strstr()` will be of use.

Comment: no; i dont have any code, its a long time i havent written any code in C and just to fix this thing up quickly...though i will try to write something up and test...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) function. It lets you find a *pointer* to the first occurrence of a specific string (say, `"Group:"`) inside another string. Once you have two pointers (to the beginning and to the end of your string) you can allocate enough memory using `malloc` (don't forget the terminating zero `'\0'`), use `memcpy` to copy the characters, and finally zero-terminate your string.

```
int main() {
    char ac_auto_lvalue[] = "ONLY / GROUP: OTHERS EXAMPLE /-----------------------------";
    // Adding 7 to compensate for the length of "GROUP: "
    const char *p1 = strstr(ac_auto_lvalue, "GROUP: ")+7;
    const char *p2 = strstr(p1, " /");
    size_t len = p2-p1;
    char *res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    strncpy(res, p1, len);
    res[len] = '\0';
    printf("'%s'\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use strstr for Group, increment that pointer by the length of Group (6).

Comment: do the same thing with character /. let say address for the pointer pointing the end of Group (which is 'p') is held by char* a, and address of '/' is help by another pointer char*b, then you can use memcpy for copying between these two pointers.